# GC.GetTotalMemory(false) returns very less memory in comparison with TaskManager reports

Tags: c#, sorting, io, mergesort

I am writing an ExternalMergeSort algorithm for sorting really huge files ( i.e. probably  20 50 GB or even 100 GB / of text files ).

For this reason, I need to split the files into equivalent chunks and then need to merge them as per the external merge sort algorithm. This should sort the files in an efficient way as per the host computer RAM.

So that's why I am dynamically querying free space and allocating a portion of it for internal sort.

I am using  `GC.GetTotalMemory(false)` and then using half of what it returns.

**First of all is it a good way?** Otherwise, what could be the more efficient way?

**Secondly: It just returns a few bytes instead of what I could see from Task Manager**. Task Manager shows clearly that I have 6.5 GB free while the above method returns only `1855904` which is very very low and further I need half of it.

So I don't understand the returned figure from this method. Does this method return free memory or some other legitimate methods in C# available that return what TaskManager shows?

Am I missing something?
Note: I could have 100-GB or 50-GB files and I need to select the most suitable and best splitting mechanism of files in a balanced manner. This might also include 5 GB or 10 GB small files.

Comment: Is your app 64bit or 32bit? - and what you are looking for seems to be `GC.GetGCMemoryInfo().TotalAvailableMemoryBytes` | https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.getgcmemoryinfo?view=net-7.0 | https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gcmemoryinfo.totalavailablememorybytes?view=net-7.0#system-gcmemoryinfo-totalavailablememorybytes

Comment: I think it provided total available and not free available. I need free available. However I could see something from PerformanceCounter object. But for that case I need to add libary of PerformaceCounter

Comment: Moreover my app is 64 bit of course.